# NSMutableArray's count method causes a bad access error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nslog

I see a few similar questions, but no simple answers. I'm just playing around with NSMutableArray's to get a feel for them before I actually use them in my real project. For some reason, it's giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try to call count on the array, and I can't figure out why.

```
    - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application 
{   
    // Create window and make key
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSMutableArray* test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"first!"], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"second!"], nil];
    [test insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"inserted"] atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", [test objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [test objectAtIndex:1]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [test objectAtIndex:2]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [test count]); //bad access here
}
```

All the inserting and accessing EXCEPT the count method work just fine. I don't see why this isn't working, and would greatly appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The `%@` format specifier prints objects. The return value of `-count` is just an unsigned integer. You should use the format specifier `%u` for that type.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Thanks a lot! Seems like a weird error to get for just having the wrong format specifier, haha.

Comment: @TNTisCOOL: No, it's not weird once you know why it crashes. The `%@` specifier wants the *address* of an object and wants to call `[theObject description]` on it. When you use `[test count]` you actually pass a number like 3 that is then interpreted as an address, but `3` would be an invalid address and trying to access it (dereference it) causes the crash.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thanks! I wish I had the reputation to give you an up vote.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `[test count]` returns an `NSUInteger` not a pointer (to an `NSObject`). Try this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%u", [test count]);
```

Note that using `%d` also works, but `%u` is preferred.

Comment: Since the return value is a `NSUInteger` you should use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Strictly %u is for unsigned int, while NSUInteger is more likely to be unsigned long.

Answer (score 1):

`- (NSUInteger)count;` returns an `NSUInteger`.

Use this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%u", [test count]); //bad access here
```

Comment: It returns an `NSUInteger`, not an `NSInteger`

Comment: Aaand.. to clarify, the bad access occurs because the `"%@"` format assumes that the handed argument is an `NSObject`, and tries to call the method `-description`, which should return an `NSString*`, but since `NSUInteger` is just a primitive, it cannot respond to such methods.

Answer (score 0):

`count` is working just fine. It does however return a `NSUInteger` primitive and not a pointer to a `NSObject` subclass. The `%@` string formatter expects a point to an object and logs the `NSString` returned from that object's `-description` method. When you pass it a `NSUInteger` `NSLog` assumes it to be an object pointer and dutifully tries to send a `-description` message to memory address 3 which causes that EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.